# Finding duplicates in a lot of images using SIFT

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, sift

I have a source image and thousands of context images. I want to know if the source image is a cropped, blurred, or rotated version of any of the destination images. I am using SIFT based image matching algorithm to identify duplicated images. It takes 2 images and tells whether 1 is the cropped, blurred or rotated version of the other images like this:

```
def get_sift_results(img1,img2):
  MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 1000

  img1 = cv2.imread(img1, 0)          # queryImage
  img2 = cv2.imread(img2, 0) # trainImage

  # Initiate SIFT detector
  sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

  # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
  kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
  kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)



  FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
  index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
  search_params = dict(checks = 50)

  flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

  matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

  # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
  good = []
  for m,n in matches:
      if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
          good.append(m)


  if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
      src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
      dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

      M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
      matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

      h,w, = img1.shape
      pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
      dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

      img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)
      print("Duplictae Images")
      return True
  else:
      print ("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
      matchesMask = None
      return False
```

The solution works fine and gives the results in 5-6 seconds per pair of images. How can I optimize it to find duplicates from thousands of images? I have tried storing the descriptors for each image and passing them to flann but that is also taking lots of time and space. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d93/group__img__hash.html was made exactly for that purpose

Comment: You could perform some kind of cascade by first using cheapest comparators like image hashes or color histograms, with a very sensitive threshold, followed by the expensive SIFT approach on all still possible pairs.